# Definition of BinarySearch and RegistryKey?

Tags: .net, documentation, binary-search

How come the metadata comment header for `BinarySearch` method is talking about `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`?

[image]

Edit:

```
#region Assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll
#endregion
```

Comment: Which .NET version and decompiler are you using?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski edited the question